# C++ overload >> operator with different interaction based on which side of >>

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

I was wondering if it is possible to have overload the C++ >> operator in this way

```
Account& operator>> (double left, Account &right)
{
    right.deposit(left);
    return right;
}

Account& operator>> (Account &left, double right)
{
    left.withdraw(right);
    return left;
}
```

I was wondering if the >> operator had this functionality
so I could do something like this

```
account1 >> 200 >> account2
```

Which would withdraw 200 from the first account and then deposit it into the second account.

Comment: What happened when you tried to compile this?

Comment: I get the error that says "Cannot overload functions distinguished by return type alone"

Comment: be carefull of parenthesis in this. Expressions are evalutated left to right, so in order to do what you want you should have one of the two returning the int value so it is not Account& >> Account&, which is what your program seems to do. But this is completely legit c++

Comment: I strongly recommend using a function (e.g., `account.transfer(200, account2);` or a fluent function chain (e.g., `account1.transfer(200).to(account2);`.  (I'm not a fan of fluent function chains, but I'm less of a fan of trying to coerce `operator>>` as a fluent chaining mechanism.)

Comment: An exception could break the "function chain" or the chain of overloaded operators. That would be a "money leak" - money gets withdrawn but the exception eats it before it gets deposited. So better implement money transfer using a single function - it either fully fails or fully succeeds.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As described, this is not going to work for the following simple reason:

```
account1 >> 200 ...
```

When this gets evaluated this ends up calling the following overload:

```
Account& operator>> (Account &left, double right)
```

Your attention is drawn to the fact that this overload returns an `Account &`. That's declared right there, in black and white. Let's keep going:

```
... >> account2
```

And now, the left-hand side of this `operator>>` is now an `Account &`, what the overload returned. It is not a `double` anymore. And it needs to be a `double` in order for the other overload to pick up the slack, and bring it home. That's how overloaded operators work in C++.

The simplest solution is probably to simply return a double value from the first overload:

```
double operator>> (Account &left, double right)
{
    left.withdraw(right);
    return right;
}
```

Now the result of this expression is a `double` value, which will have a much easier time getting the other overloaded `operator>>` to come into picture.

Comment: This is great and solves an issue I would end up having in the future however the error that the function cannot be distinguished by return type alone still appears. Even though the function parameters are swapped.

Comment: This is not much of information to go on, for any kind of a discussion. These kinds of compilation errors have many different reason, and is likely to have a completely unrelated reason. You are welcome to post another question about this error, and make sure that any shown code (that causes this error) in the new question meets all requirements for a [mre]. so that everyone else can cut/paste it, ***exactly as shown*** into an empty file, then compile and reproduce the error. That's the only practical way these kinds of errors can be diagnosed.

Answer (score 3):

As was pointed out, your `operator>>()` returns an `Account&` in both cases, i.e., you can't chain the operators as indicated. You could use them individually, though. However, it seems, that isn't intended.

You *could* achieve your effective goal by returning something like a `Withdraw(account, amount)` entity from `operator>> (Account& account, double amount)` and have the second operator be `operator>> (Withdraw const& withdraw, Account&)`. The second operator would then trigger the transaction. Technically doable but I'm not convinced to that's the way to go.

```
#include <utility>

struct Account {
    double withdraw(double amount) { return amount; }
    double deposit(double amount) { return amount; }
};
struct Withdraw {
    Account& account;
    double   amount;
    double do_it() && { return account.withdraw(amount); }
};

void operator>> (Withdraw && left, Account &right)
{
    right.deposit(std::move(left).do_it());
}

Withdraw operator>> (Account &left, double right)
{
    return Withdraw{left, right};
}

int main() {
    Account a1, a2;
    a1 >> 200 >> a2;
}
```

Whether that approach is advisable I'm not so sure. I think I'd be confused by the code and would be better off with the operations being named. It *may* however, still be reasonable to build an operation object which is eventually executed as a transaction, combining multiple individual operations.